# SQL Server : foreign key relation with another database: best approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am trying to find best solution for this scenario and have researching but couldn't find a best way.

We are providing Service A to the clients, Service A has set of schema structure. Now we are in the process of building another/different application which will be Service B with separate schema structure. What is the best way that I can keep one consistent customer and their users in both schemas.

1. I have looked into FK relation with different database but it is not recommended
2. I am not sold on the replicating the table in the other database

   - Schema A: Customer table, user table, service A schema
   - Schema B: Customer table, user table, Service B Schema

Any recommendation or resources you can point me to?

Comment: This is too vague to get a proper answer. Please edit your question to show the DDL for the current schema behind Service A.

Comment: What was your reason to go with a separate database? You can have a separate schema structure in the same database, with FK between schemas. This is one of the things that schemas were designed for.

Comment: Didn't think of multiple schemas. Let me re-read it and close it if I am able to find solution.